# Angular 2 gives "TypeError: emitter.subscribe is not a function"

Tags: angular

I have creating a little app using angular 2 and i create 2 component call app.component.ts and sidkik.component.ts in my app I have try to import sidkik.component.ts in to app.component.ts and use sidkik's sidkik tag in app.component and it's give below error in console. please help me with this problem.

**erorr**

```
angular2.dev.js:23524 EXCEPTION: TypeError: emitter.subscribe is not a function in [heroes in AppComponent@3:6]
```

**app.component.js**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {SideKikComponent} from './classes/sidekik.component';

interface Hero {
 id: number;
 name: string;
 sidekik:string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl:'app/views/heros.html',
  directives: [SideKikComponent],
  styleUrls: ['app/css/site.css']
})

export class AppComponent { 
  public title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  public heroes =HEROS;
  public selectedHero: Hero;

  onSelect(hero: Hero) { 
    this.selectedHero = hero; 
  }
}

var HEROS: Hero[] =[
    {"id":1,"name":"SuperMan","sidekik":"one"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Captain America","sidekik":"two"},
    {"id":3,"name":"Thor","sidekik":"three"},
    {"id":4,"name":"Iorn Man","sidekik":"four"},
    {"id":5,"name":"Ant Man","sidekik":"five"}
];
```

and
**sidkik.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector:'sidekik',
  events:['hit'],
  properties:['define'],
  template: `
    <sidekik (click) = "hit(define)"></sidekik>
  `,

 })

 export class SideKikComponent{
    hit(define:string){
    console.log(define);
  }
}
```

Comment: There are many mistakes .. can you share the code on github or plunker ?

Comment: ok i will send the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is being caused by the way you have defined your Component. In particular the `events: ['hit'],` Angular expects this to be an `EventEmitter` instance in your component that will fire events from the `SidekikComponent` instances that other components can subscribe to. What you have defined as `hit` though is a function that will be called called on click events.

As others have pointed out you have other problems in the snippets you provided, for example `template:` shouldn't contain the selector for the component inside it.

Comment: The `sidekik` tag should be used in the template you want these components to exist in. In the template you define there you should use the elements (or other components) the `sidekik` component is made up of.